# Adding missing sub tags using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to extract the person names from the below XML. I have used the below code and got the output (ORIGINAL). But I want even the missing items.

The 4th person's the middle name is missing so only three names where extracted.

Sample XML:

```
<author>
    <persName>
        <forename>Esayas</forename>
         <middlename>K</middlename>
         <surname>Gudina</surname>
    <lb/>
         <marker>1*</marker>,
    </persName>
    <persName>
         <forename>Solomon</forename>
         <middlename>T</middlename>
         <surname>Amade</surname>
    <lb/>
         <marker>2</marker> ,
    </persName>
    <persName>
        <forename>Fessahaye</forename>
         <middlename>A</middlename>
         <surname>Tesfamichael</surname>
    <lb/>
         <marker>3</marker> and
    </persName>
    <persName>
         <forename>Rana</forename>
        <surname>Ram</surname>
    <lb/>
         <marker>4</marker>
    </persName>
</author>
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import codecs

name = []

with codecs.open("D:/...../2F1472-6823-11-19.authors.tei.xml", "r", "utf-8") as infile:
    soup = bs(infile, "html5lib")      

pn = soup.find_all('persname')


for i in pn:
    try:
        if len((i.find('forename')).text) != 0:
            fn = (i.find('forename')).text
        else:
            fn =""
        if len((i.find('middlename')).text) != 0:
            mn = (i.find('middlename')).text
        else:
            mn=""
        if len((i.find('surname')).text) != 0:
            sn = (i.find('surname')).text
        else:
            sn ="" 
        name.append(fn+" "+mn+" "+sn)
    except:
        print ("")
```

Output:

```
INDEX   TYPE       SIZE   VALUE
0     unicode       1     Esayas K Gudina
1     unicode       1     Solomon T Amade
2     unicode       1     Fessahaye A Tesfamichael
```

Expected output:

```
INDEX   TYPE       SIZE   VALUE
0     unicode       1     Esayas K Gudina
1     unicode       1     Solomon T Amade
2     unicode       1     Fessahaye A Tesfamichael
3     unicode       1     Rana   Ram
```

Comment: Would you throw out a result if only the middle name was found? would you assume that tag was wrong and it was in fact the first name? What if you only had a last name? seems like you just need to decide what you want to do in each possible case, and account for it in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import codecs

name = []

with codecs.open("tei.xml", "r", "utf-8") as infile:
    soup = bs(infile, "html5lib")
pn = soup.find_all('persname')


for i in pn:
    try:
        if i.find('forename') is not None and len(i.find('forename').text) != 0:
            fn = (i.find('forename')).text
        else:
            fn =""
        if i.find('middlename') is not None and len(i.find('middlename').text) != 0:
            mn = i.find('middlename').text
        else:
            mn=""
        if i.find('surname') is not None and  len(i.find('surname').text) != 0:
            sn = i.find('surname').text
        else:
            sn =""
        name.append(fn+" "+mn+" "+sn)
    except:
        print ("")
print (name)
```

Outputs:

```
[u'Esayas K Gudina', u'Solomon T Amade', u'Fessahaye A Tesfamichael', u'Rana  Ram']
```

Comment: Using the `try` block here seems like it's causing more problems than it solves..

Comment: @Aaron your probably right but I wanted to change the original poster's code as little as possible.